# To check the length of required field in file (using shell script), and if does not match discard those records

Tags: ksh

I have following details in my test file.

```
HEADER
A12345678|PROCESS
B12345678|PROCESS
C12345678|GOOD
D12345678|GOOD
E123456789|PROCESS
F123456|GOOD
G12345678|PROCESS
8|TRAILER
```

What I want is to check if the first column is having length of 9. If it is we will proceed with those records, and if not we will discard the records.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code to show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: is pipe your delimiter ? @sid

Comment: Do you want me to share the exact code? I believe you are not. Here it goes -

Comment: export GOOD_FILE =`nawk -F"|"  '(length($1) == 9)'  test.txt >> ${GOOD_DIR}test_$BUSDATE.txt`
export BAD_FILE =`nawk -F"|"  '(length($1)!=9)'  test.txt >>${REJ_DIR}test_$BUSDATE.rej`
export FAILURE_DEST=`cat ${SOURCE_DIR}failure_mail_list.txt | tr -s '\n' ' '`

if [$BAD_FILE -gt 0 ]
then
echo "File contains malformed records.\n\n Please get in touch with source Team for further action and investigation\n\n Thanks"|mailx -s "Error in completion of validation" $FAILURE_DEST

elif [$BAD_FILE -eq 0]
echo "The file does not contain any corrupt record"
exit 1;
fi

Answer (score 0):

You can process lines given by `egrep '^.{9}\|'  testfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this once :

```
    set -x
    cat file1|cut -d "|" -f1 > file_ab
    ln_count=`cat file_ab | wc -l` 


    i=1
    while [ $ln_count -ne 0 ]
    do
        column_content=`cat file2|head -$i|tail -1`
        len=`echo $column_content | wc -c`
        len1=`expr $len - 1`
        if [ $len1 -eq 9 ] 
        then
            echo 'I am in if'
            cat file1 | head -$i | tail -1 >> file3
        else
            echo 'I am in else'
            cat file1 | head -$i | tail -1 >> file4
        fi

        i=`expr $i + 1`
        ln_count=`expr $ln_count - 1`


    done
```

Comment: There are a lot of improvents possible. Try using `$()` and not backtics for subprocesses and look how this works: `cat file1 | IFS="|" while read column_content otherfields; do` where you can avoid heads and tails.